# Cron Job only specific months

Tags: cron, cron-task, cronexpression

I would like to set up a cron task to run a script every first day of every month except 1st january. How can I do that?

Could I try something like that: 0  0   1   2-12    * ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can be something like below:

`0 0 1 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 *`

Comment: Thanks Rushabh Patel, I'll try this solution and I'll let you know.

Answer (score 7):

```
Minutes [0-59]
|   Hours [0-23]
|   |   Days [1-31]
|   |   |   Months [1-12]
|   |   |   |   Days of the Week [Numeric, 0-6]
|   |   |   |   |
*   *   *   *   * home/path/to/command/the_command.sh
```

This is can be usefull for you to identify the usage.

Comment: This is not an answer.